# Composite keys in SQLite for Xamarin Forms

Tags: sqlite, xamarin.forms, sqlite.net

I need use more than one primary key in sqlite database in Xamarin Forms. I use the SQLite.NET-PCL but not contains this feature. Exist another way for do this?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mnh1G.png)